# How to grow ScrollToBottom to fill the height of the screen?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-chatelet-6o9uh?file=/src/Logs.js) is a code sandbox that defines a `Logs` React component and works great.

It uses react-scroll-to-bottom to show a page with a header and some logs. Note that because we use a flexbox, the size of log section grows perfectly to fit the height of the screen.

Now I want to place this `Logs` component inside an `App` component. The problem is that now the log section is too tall and another scrollbar appears in addition to the scroll-to-bottom scrollbar. You can see this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-jang-e249p?file=/src/App.js).

I think this is because we use `100vh` for the height of the `Logs` component. The problem is, if I change this to `100%`, ScrollToBottom breaks and displays the full log content as if it were a normal div. It seems like ScrollToBottom requires a specific type of height such as `px`, `em` or `vh` to work. I'm not sure where to go from here.

How do I grow ScrollToBottom to fill the height of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is indeed with using 100vh. You're not accounting for the height of the header.  You could change the height to something like 90vh and it seems to work.  Or even give it a defined height in px.

Comment: Is there a way to use flexbox to make it automatically fill the space it's in? using 90vh seems like it will work for some screen sizes but not others.